# Splitting List into sublists based on unique values

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8, classification, decision-tree

I have a list of lists:
`List<ArrayList<String>> D = new ArrayList<>();`

When it's populated, it might look like:
["A", "B", "Y"]
["C", "D", "Y"]
["A", "D", "N"]

I want to split the list of lists into partitions based on the unique attribute values (let's say index 1).

So the attribute at index 1 has two unique values, "B" and "D", so I want to split into:
["A", "B", "Y"]

["C", "D", "Y"]
["A", "D", "N"]

and put those into a `List<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> sublists;`

Is there a smart way of doing this, or do I just do something like this:

```
List<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> sublists = new ArrayList<>();
int featIdx = 1;

// generate the subsets
for (ArrayList<String> record : D) {
    String val = record.get(featIdx);

    // check if the value exists in sublists
    boolean found = false;
    for (ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> entry : sublists) {
        if (entry.get(0).get(featIdx).equals(val)) {
            entry.add(record);
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!found) {
        sublists.add(new ArrayList<>());
        sublists.get(sublists.size()-1).add(record);
    }
}
```

This is a step from the C4.5 Decision Tree [algorithm](http://www.otnira.com/2013/03/25/c4-5/), so if anyone has experience in this, I would appreciate if you could let me know if this is the right approach to generating the sublists.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With Java 8 you can use the `groupingBy` collector:

```
Map<String, List<List<String>>> grouped = D.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(list -> list.get(1)));
Collection<List<List<String>>> sublists = grouped.values();
```

or as suggested by @AlexisC:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.collectingAndThen;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;

Collection<List<List<String>>> sublists = D.stream()
             .collect(collectingAndThen(groupingBy(list -> list.get(1)), Map::values));
```

Comment: .. or `Collection<List<List<String>>> subLists = D.stream().collect(collectingAndThen(groupingBy(x -> x.get(1)), Map::values));`

Comment: Although, in this case, I doubt there is a huge difference than what you did (if you called values directly after `collect`)

Comment: I guess, `collectingAndThen` is only useful when the resulting `Collector` is passed into another compound `Collector`. Otherwise, it’s just a more complicated way of calling a method on the result.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to create a `HashMap<String, List<List<String>>>`, and group those lists there. Then just call `map.values()` to get `Collection<List<List<String>>>`.

```
List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(Lists.newArrayList("A", "B", "Y"));
list.add(Lists.newArrayList("C", "D", "Z"));
list.add(Lists.newArrayList("A", "D", "X"));
list.add(Lists.newArrayList("D", "C", "A"));

Map<String, List<List<String>>> mapped = list.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(li -> li.get(1))); 
System.out.println(mapped);
Collection<List<List<String>>> groupedList = mapped.values();
```